# `git status` shows a bunch of random files and folders that I never added and aren't a part of my project directory?

Tags: git, github, version-control

When I use the `git status` command, I see a huge list of files and folders that I've never added to any project, like the /Desktop or /AppData folders or NTUSER.dat files. These are all listed under "Untracked files". There are also files from previous projects that are still in my staging area even though I've switched directories and added a completely different remote (and removed the old remote).

Also, when I use `git status` I get a bunch of warnings such as "could not open directory 'My Documents/': Permission Denied". Also not sure why it's doing this.

I made a completely new repo and started a new shell in an empty directory on my computer, and `git status` is still showing all the files it was before.

Sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm still learning how to use git and github. Can anyone offer any advice? I'd appreciate any help whatsoever.

Comment: You did `git init` in your home directory, so now Git thinks you want to put the whole thing, desktop, appdata and all, under source control.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please add some details about, how did you create a new copy in an empty folder? I mean did you make a new clone using `$git clone` or did you copy paste all files form old directory to new one?

sorry for a question here, too low on reputation to add commend :(